# BindAttribute doesn't seem to work in ASP.Net MVC Core (2.0.8)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use the Bind attribute to include only specific properties in my model. I know I can use a view model and only specify the properties I need, but I can't use that because the code has to run through some static code analysis that triggers an error if the Bind attribute is not present, and I can't change that rule (it's not controlled by me).

This is what I tried.

Model:

```cs
[Bind("One")]
public class SomeModel 
{
    public int One { get; set; }
    public int Two { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method:

```cs
[HttpPost("foo")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public IActionResult Foo([FromBody] SomeModel model)
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

What I'm sending in POST:

```
{
    "One": 1,
    "Two": 2
}
```

Response I'm getting:

```
{
    "One": 1,
    "Two": 2
}
```

I also tried putting the `[Bind]` attribute right before the controller method parameter, but it doesn't work.

So, the problem I'm having is that "Two" still gets assigned a value, even though I explicitly told that I only want "One" to be bound.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Remove the from body attribute and just use the bind on the parameter and see if that works

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, but I also tried it and it doesn't work. In that case I get 0 in both properties, which means the binding didn't work at all. I then tried a few more combinations (adding `JsonProperty` attributes, changing the case of properties) with no luck.

Comment: @asterite Will it meet your requirement by `JsonIgnore` like `    public class SomeModel
    {
        public int One { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int Two { get; set; }
    }
`, otherwise, I am afriad you will need to implement your own custom model binding [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1](Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core)

Comment: I think the rule requires a Bind attribute, there's nothing else I can do. It's strange that it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `BindAttribute` doesn't work as expected when the model is passed via the body in the request.
When it's passed via the QueryString, then it works as expected.

You can test this out using the following sample code:

This is the model:

```
[Bind(include: nameof(MinX))]
public class ValueModel
{
    [JsonProperty("min-x")]
    public string MinX { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("min-y")]
    public string MinY { get; set; }
}
```

The API methods where it works as expected:

```
[HttpGet()]
public ActionResult<string> Get([FromQuery] ValueModel value)
{
    return new OkObjectResult($"MinX={value.MinX}; MinY={value.MinY}");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromQuery]ValueModel value)
{
    return new OkObjectResult($"MinX={value.MinX}; MinY={value.MinY}");
}
```

The API methods where it doesn't work as expected:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]ValueModel value)
{
    return new OkObjectResult($"MinX={value.MinX}; MinY={value.MinY}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `[Bind]` doesn't work for JSON, so there's no way around this, at least for my use case.

See: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8005 and https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5731

Comment: Is there any issue with using `JsonIgnore`? `[Bind]` is not work for Json is caused by that for convert `application/json` to model is achieved by `JsonInputFormatter`. As my test, `JsonIngore` will only map `One` from request to model.

Comment: The issue is the policy. We (the client) is using Veracode Scan and that's a rule they have ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ . I can use `JsonIgnore` or any other method, but it will fail the Veracode Scan...

Answer (score 0):

The `[Bind]` attribute must be on the parameter. You cannot define it at a class level. The reason @Nkosi's suggestion failed is that you still also need `[FromBody]` since you're posting JSON. In other words:

```
[HttpPost("foo")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public IActionResult Foo([FromBody][Bind("One")] SomeModel model)
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

FWIW, whoever setup you static analysis is a moron and should be called such, repeatedly and with much vigor.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that doesn't work (I mentioned in the question that I already tried this approach).

Comment: The BindAttribute can be declared on a class.  See MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.bindattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: @FrederikGheysels: What in the world are you talking about? The linked doc in no way implies that this can be used on a class, and you didn't even bother to link to the *right* `BindAttribute` docs (notice the `System.Web` namespace).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link; here is the correct one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.bindattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1   Notice the AttributeUsage attribute where it is specified that it can be applied on classes and parameters.

Comment: That doesn't mean it will actually *do* something though. In this case, the OP was trying to apply it to a model class, which won't do anything. I've never thought to try, but it's possible you might be able to apply it to a controller class, not sure why you would. Regardless, the sheer fact that you are allowed to apply it to a class does not mean that it will actually do anything meaningful there.