# Using BindAttribute with JSON formatter - ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there any way that I can use `[Bind]` when using JSON? I have a model and I want to restrict what properties can be submitted (officially its [only available when using form data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attributes-for-complex-type-targets)).

Is there a legit reason why its not implemented for JSON or they just haven't gotten to it yet. And if its intentional, what's the right way to handle a case where you want to restrict access to some properties?

Any insight, ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is by design, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143055/bindattribute-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-asp-net-mvc-core-2-0-8/. There are references to MVC issues (pre-Core, but still relevant) that talk about it. Wasn't aware.

Comment: I know that the is how it behaves (hence the link in my question), my question is if its for a reason and if yes how to go when you need this kind of functionality

Answer (score 0):

That is because when using json(`application/json`) to post data to server side , asp.net core will use `JsonInputFormatter` to deserialize the json and add to model , the `[bind]` which implementing `IPropertyFilterProvider` won't fire in this scenario . The workaround is to use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute which works in Json.Net , so use another model class which doesn't contain the ignored properties .